# Protobuf, Dart - Generate nullable types from WKT wrappers

Tags: dart, protocol-buffers

[Protobuf code generation for C# specifies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/grpc-for-wcf-developers/protobuf-data-types#nullable-types):

> For values that require explicit null, such as using `int?` in your C#
> code, Protobuf's "Well Known Types" include wrappers that are compiled
> to nullable C# types.

```protobuf
syntax = "proto3"

import "google/protobuf/wrappers.proto";

message Person {

    ...
    google.protobuf.Int32Value age = 5;

}
```

The generated type of the `Age` property from this example is `int?` in C#, but `Int32Value` in Dart.

**Is there a way to also generate `int?` type for Dart?**

I'm using [Google.Protobuf](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Protobuf) package to generate C# code and [protoc_plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/protoc_plugin) to generate Dart code. Both are official code generators by Google.

Comment: So, I learned about the added on the wire overhead that wrappers create and decided against using them.